# How to get Startup Folder in java?

Tags: java

*Hi..i'm looking for a function that's can return the startup folder path in java
wish that's work on windows xp/7/vista*

The startup folder which is in Windows is the folder where all applications in it start on login. It should look something like this:

> `C:\Users\USR_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: -1 for still not having changed the question to be in any way clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
File file = new File("");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath());
```

If you define no path in the `File` constructor, it assumes the current directory.

Did you mean this?

Edit: I guess not. Sorry, if you don't post a clear question, i can't help.
You should read [Stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: 'doesn't work' is not a very accurate description of the problem.

Comment: i want to extratct zip file into the startup folder,my unzip class have tow paramtre inputfile(zip) and the output folder(startup),want a function that return startup folder on differnet windows version

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea what you exactly talking about. Please edit your post and add your source-code into it. I suggest to read the FAQ from Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
File f = new File(".");
String startupFolder = f.getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". What do you want it to do? What is the error that you see?